# Convergence of $\sum_n \frac{1}{f(n)}$ equivalent to that of $\sum_n \frac{f^{-1}(n)}{n^2}$ (tough)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f:[1,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be an increasing positive function that tends to $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, prove that $\sum_n \frac{1}{f(n)}$ is convergent if and only if $\sum_n \frac{f^{-1}(n)}{n^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: Did you try an integral test?

Comment: Let see $f(n)=\ln n$.

Comment: The statement holds for ln$n$ since both 1/ln$n$ and $e^n/n^2$ sum up to $\infty$. Didn't get anywhere with an integral test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of proof:** Note that for any $n \in \Bbb N$: $x = f^{-1}(n)$ is such that $m \leq x \iff f(m) \leq n$. Equivalently: $\lfloor f^{-1}(n) \rfloor$ counts the number of integers $i = 1,2,\dots,\lfloor f^{-1}(n) \rfloor$ such that $f(i) \leq n$.

With that, we have
$$
\sum_{n} \frac 1{f(n)} = \frac 1{f(1)} + \frac 1{f(2)} + \cdots \leq \\
\underbrace{\frac 1{1} + \cdots + \frac 1{1}}_{\lfloor f^{-1}(1)\rfloor} \; + \;
\underbrace{\frac 1{2} + \cdots + \frac 1{2}}_{\lfloor f^{-1}(2)\rfloor - \lfloor f^{-1}(1)\rfloor} \; + \;
\underbrace{\frac 1{3} + \cdots + \frac 1{3}}_{\lfloor f^{-1}(3)\rfloor - \lfloor f^{-1}(2)\rfloor} \; + \; \cdots = \\
\lfloor f^{-1}(1) \rfloor +  \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\lfloor f^{-1}(n+1)\rfloor - \lfloor f^{-1}(n)\rfloor}{n+1} \approx\\
f^{-1}(1) +  \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{ f^{-1}(n+1) -  f^{-1}(n)}{n+1}
$$
From there, a [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) leads to the desired result (or at least, leads to something close enough for a limit comparison test).  We can construct a similar lower bound, leading to the conclusion that the first will converge if and only the second does.

Answer (score 1):

**Incomplete idea:** Try an integral test, as Pedro's comment suggests.  Note that with the substitution $u = f(x)$ (that is, $x = f^{-1}(u)$) we find that
$$
\int \frac 1{f(x)}\,dx = 
\int \frac 1u \cdot \frac{df^{-1}}{du} \,du
$$
Now, try integrating by parts.

Comment: Wouldn't this require $f$ to be differentiable?

Comment: @IanMedina good point. Also, one should consider separately the case in which $f^{-1}(n)/n \not \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.